# No suitable pipeline found for auth-register-login error in Express Gateway start up and get a 404 error when I POST to it

Tags: http-status-code-404, express-gateway

Pls help. I am new to Express Gateway. 
**During npm start I am getting the following errors**. I dont see any problems (being novice) any problems with gateway.config.yml and the way pipelines are configured.

When I POST a message I get Not Found.. Also attached below a simple post message..

```
2020-03-28T02:20:04.382Z [EG:gateway] debug: mounting routes for apiEndpointName auth-email-confirm, mount /auth/email-confirm/:token
2020-03-28T02:20:04.382Z [EG:gateway] debug: No suitable pipeline found for auth-email-confirm
2020-03-28T02:20:04.382Z [EG:gateway] debug: methods specified, registering for each method individually
2020-03-28T02:20:04.382Z [EG:gateway] debug: mounting routes for apiEndpointName auth-register-login, mount /auth/register-user
2020-03-28T02:20:04.382Z [EG:gateway] debug: No suitable pipeline found for auth-register-login
2020-03-28T02:20:04.382Z [EG:gateway] debug: methods specified, registering for each method individually
2020-03-28T02:20:04.382Z [EG:gateway] debug: mounting routes for apiEndpointName auth-register-login, mount /auth/login
2020-03-28T02:20:04.382Z [EG:gateway] debug: No suitable pipeline found for auth-register-login
2020-03-28T02:20:04.382Z [EG:gateway] debug: methods specified, registering for each method individually
2020-03-28T02:20:04.383Z [EG:gateway] debug: mounting routes for apiEndpointName auth-user, mount /auth/user*
2020-03-28T02:20:04.383Z [EG:gateway] debug: No suitable pipeline found for auth-user
2020-03-28T02:20:04.383Z [EG:gateway] debug: no methods specified. handle all mode.
2020-03-28T02:20:04.383Z [EG:gateway] debug: mounting routes for apiEndpointName properties, mount /property*
2020-03-28T02:20:04.383Z [EG:gateway] debug: No suitable pipeline found for properties
2020-03-28T02:20:04.383Z [EG:gateway] debug: no methods specified. handle all mode.
2020-03-28T02:20:04.383Z [EG:gateway] info: hot-reload config completed
```

Here is my gateway.config.yml:

```
http:
  port: 8080

admin:
  host: localhost
  port: 9876

apiEndpoints:
  auth-email-confirm:
    host: localhost
    path: '/auth/email-confirm/:token'
    methods: ["GET"]

  auth-register-login:
    host: localhost
    paths: ['/auth/register-user', '/auth/login']
    methods: ["POST"]

  auth-user:
    host: localhost
    path:  '/auth/user*'

  properties:
    host: localhost
    path: '/property*'

serviceEndpoints:
  auth:
    url: 'http://localhost:3003'

  properties:
    url: 'http://localhost:4004'

#policies to be used
policies:
  - log
  - proxy
  - jwt
  - request-transformer

#pipelines 
pipelines:
  # this pipeline is used for user clicking on email confirmation
  authEmailConfirmPipeline: 
    apiEndPoints: 
      - auth-email-confirm
    policies:
      - log:
          action:
            message: '${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}'
      - proxy:
          action: 
            serviceEndpoint: auth
            changeOrigin: true

  # this pipeline is used for user registration or login apis
  authRegisterPipeline: 
    apiEndPoints: # in this case we dont need to validate the jwt
      - auth-register-login
    policies:
      - log:
          action:
            message: '${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}'  
      - proxy:
          action: 
            serviceEndpoint: auth
            changeOrigin: true

  # this pipeline is used for user logout or other user update functions (roles, privileges etc)
  authPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - auth
    policies:
      - log:
          action:
            message: '${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}'
      - jwt:
          action:
            secretOrPublicKeyFile: ./.key/pubkey.pem
            checkCredentialExistence: false
      - proxy:
          action:
            serviceEndpoint: auth
            changeOrigin: true
```

Using requests.rest in visual studio code:

POST http://localhost:8080/auth/register-user
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "gurs@hotmail.com",
    "password": "ravig",
    "provider": "local",
    "firstName": "Ravi",
    "lastName": "Guduru",
    "middleName": "Udaya",
    "phones": [{"6827014411", "mobile"}]
}

Comment: I don't get the same errors starting Express Gateway (version 1.16.10). Which version are you running? Have you started the auth service listening on http://localhost:3030?

Answer (score 0):

The problem causing the "Not Found" response is in the definition of your `authRegisterPipeline` pipeline. The line:

```yaml
    apiEndPoints: # in this case we dont need to validate the jwt
```

It's apiEndpoints, not apiEndPoints! Change it to:

```yaml
    apiEndpoints: # in this case we dont need to validate the jwt
```

and the "Not Found" response should go away. (In my case, it was replaced with a "Bad Gateway" response since I don't have a service running on 3003.)

I have not observed the startup errors you describe runnning NPM version 1.16.10.